# Run time choice of method using std::bind. Problem with access to variable

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, stdbind

I need to choice the particular method of the class at the run time. To do it I use `std::bind`. Below is an example demonstrating what I do:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
class bc {
public:
    bc(int, double);
    std::function<double(double)> f; //pointer to function which will be binded with f1 or f2 
    void setVal(double v) {val = v;} //method allowing to change val

    double val;  //some variable used by f1 and f2
    double f1(double v) {return 2*v*val;} 
    double f2(double v) {return 3*v*val;}
};

bc::bc(int fid, double v)    //depends on fid the f1 or f2 is chosen for binding
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    this->val = v;
    if(fid == 1)
        f = std::bind(&bc::f1, *this, _1);
    else
        f = std::bind(&bc::f2, *this, _1);
}
```

So depends on the value of `fid` given to the constructor the necessary implementation (`f1` or `f2`) is chosen. Then in the `main`:

```
int main()
{
    bc my(1, 2.0);
    std::cout << my.f(1) << std::endl; //1
    my.setVal(5.0);
    std::cout << my.f(1) << std::endl; //2
    return 0;
}
```

The first output from string `//1` is as expected: `4` .
But the second output (`//2`) is also `4`, while it should be `10`, because the value of `val` should be changed to `5` by `my.setVal(5.0)`.

I expect that something like a copy of the class was made at the stage of binding, and the change of the `val` by `my.setVal(5.0)` have no effect on this "copy".

How can I solve this problem? Or may be there is a better way to make run time choice between several implementations of some function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*this` causes a copy of the current object to be bound, use `this` or `std::ref(*this)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Do not dereference `this` before passing it to `std::bind`:

```
    if(fid == 1)
        f = std::bind(&bc::f1, this, _1);
    else
        f = std::bind(&bc::f2, this, _1);
```

By default `std::bind` stores copies of the arguments, so you ended up with a copy of `bc` in it, and changing the `val` field of the original has no effect. Alternatively, you can use `std::reference_wrapper` to achieve the same effect:

```
    if(fid == 1)
        f = std::bind(&bc::f1, std::ref(*this), _1);
    else
        f = std::bind(&bc::f2, std::ref(*this), _1);
```